# Searching entries using ldapsearch

Tags: ldap

I am new to learning ldap authentication. Now there are two commands that I can use to search ldap directory:

First one:

```
ldapsearch -b "base directoty path" -D "cn=manager,dc=mydomain,dc=com" -W "ldap pwd"
```

Second one:

```
ldapsearch -x -b "dn of entry to be searched"
```

The first command requires my pwd, whereas the second doesn't. What is actually happening here?

Answer (score 0):

With:

> ldapsearch -b "base directoty path" -D "cn=manager,dc=mydomain,dc=com"
>   -W "ldap pwd"

You are requesting the server prompt with password "-W". to not prompt, use "-w".

With

> ldapsearch -x -b "dn of entry to be searched"

You are not providing a binddn (-D) so the search in done anonymously.
This maybe helpful:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19693-01/819-0997/auto45/index.html

Or just google for ldapsearch.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It'll surely help me.